# imageIO making button to save JFrame as PNG

Tags: java, swing, jframe, javax.imageio

I'm very confused how the imageIO works, I have this application:

[image]

I would like the save button to save all of its content in the JFrame as PNG.
However it does not work, when I tried this code:

```
ImageIO.write(JFrame, "PNG", new File("filename.png"));
```

Any replies?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write-java.awt.image.RenderedImage-java.lang.String-java.io.File-), you need to pass `ImageIO.write` an instance of `RenderedImage`.

If you have a look at the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) for `JFrame` you will find that it doesn't implement `RenderedImage`, hence your problem.

If you have a look at just about [any example of `Image.write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html) you'll find that almost always use a [`BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) because it, unlike `JFrame`, does implement `RenderedImage`

Okay, so the question becomes, "how do I paint the `JFrame` to a `BufferedImage`?"

The answer, if you look around, is quite simple.

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
frame.printAll(g2d);
g2d.dispose();
```

And now, you can save it...

```
ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("filename.png"));
```

Comment: Will I add the bufferedImage code to the save button or to the entire JFrame?

Comment: That depends on when you want to save the image

Comment: I want to save the image on click of the save button, could you tell me where do I put the code?

Comment: Put the code where you need to use. There's no point taking a snapshot of the frame before you want to save it

Comment: @MadProgrammer, finally see a concrete reason for using printAll() over paint(). (The double buffer doesn't seem to be an issue in that performance is still the same). On Windows, when using paint() the frame titlebar and border are just black. Using printAll() I do get a titlebar and border, however, it looks more like the Metal titlebar and border instead of the Windows LAF. So, on Windows at least, it still looks like the only way to get an image of the proper titllebar and border is to use the Robot.

Comment: @camickr I've also had issues with components which haven't been realised causing NPE when using paint and been black because of the double buffering, besides I think the op would prefer to capture the content pane and not the frame itself, but what do I know 

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Screen Image](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) class.

It provides overloaded methods to paint components or a part of a component. The logic will then use either:

1. The Robot class to paint a frame, or
2. Swing painting to paint Swing components. (painting is more efficient than using the Robot).